# iPhone UITableView "More" Cell? How to implement?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Having trouble figuring out how to add a new row into the bottom of a UITableView that says "Load More Results" in a different format than the rest of the UITableView's cells?

This is how Mail.app works on the iPhone. Anybody done this? Is it super-obvious and I missed it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Hah! The UITableView has a footer and header view.

Just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can check to see if this is your row (last row) and either make a simple `UITableViewCell` or return an instance of a subclass of `UITableViewCell` which does what you want.

There isn't anything too tricky.  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` does not need to return the same "type" of cell for every row in a table.